# I am getting NaN values in the dataframe after applying OneHotEncoding, any idea on how to get rid of those?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

I am working on a clustering project and got a dataset with no null values in it.
There are 2 categorical columns gender and vehical_type which I need to convert to numerics, so I have applied One hot encoder on the dataset but the output has NaN values in it.

Any idea where I am doing it wrong or is there any way to overcome this?

dataset details :

```
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   gender         52989 non-null  object        
 1   agecat         52989 non-null  float64       
 2   date_of_birth  52989 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 3   credit_score   52989 non-null  float64       
 4   veh_age        52989 non-null  int64         
 5   veh_body       52989 non-null  object        
 6   veh_value      52989 non-null  float64       
 7   numclaims      52989 non-null  int64         
 8   claimcst0      52989 non-null  float64       
 9   year           52989 non-null  int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(3), object(2)
memory usage: 4.4+ MB
```

one hot encoder code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# creating instance of one-hot-encoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc_df = 
pd.DataFrame(encoder.fit_transform(df_updated_new1[['gender',
'veh_body']]).toarray())
enc_df.columns = encoder.get_feature_names(['gender', 'veh_body'])
enc_df

# merge with main df df_updated_new1 on key values
df_updated_enc = df_updated_new1.join(enc_df)
df_updated_enc

# drop column_2 and column_4
df_updated_enc = df_updated_enc.drop(['gender', 'veh_body'], axis =1)
df_updated_enc.tail()
```

output has null values in it :

```
Data columns (total 22 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   agecat          52989 non-null  float64
 1   credit_score    52989 non-null  float64
 2   veh_age         52989 non-null  int64  
 3   veh_value       52989 non-null  float64
 4   numclaims       52989 non-null  int64  
 5   claimcst0       52989 non-null  float64
 6   year            52989 non-null  int64  
 7   gender_F        46510 non-null  float64
 8   gender_M        46510 non-null  float64
 9   veh_body_BUS    46510 non-null  float64
 10  veh_body_CONVT  46510 non-null  float64
 11  veh_body_COUPE  46510 non-null  float64
 12  veh_body_HBACK  46510 non-null  float64
 13  veh_body_HDTOP  46510 non-null  float64
 14  veh_body_MCARA  46510 non-null  float64
 15  veh_body_MIBUS  46510 non-null  float64
 16  veh_body_PANVN  46510 non-null  float64
 17  veh_body_RDSTR  46510 non-null  float64
 18  veh_body_SEDAN  46510 non-null  float64
 19  veh_body_STNWG  46510 non-null  float64
 20  veh_body_TRUCK  46510 non-null  float64
 21  veh_body_UTE    46510 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(19), int64(3)
```

Comment: It's better if you please add your code along with your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the code snippet please have a look

Comment: Right before you merge the encoded dataframe with the original, compare the indexes of the two dataframes. My guess is that the encoded dataframe has only 46510 rows. If so, you need to figure out which rows are missing and why.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've checked the shape of that encoded dataframe and it shows that the rows are fine. (52989, 15)

Answer (score 1):

I have reset the index and now everything is fine.